# Laravel How to custom user table when i use JWT authenticate

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am on a Laravel project, I want to know How to use the encry_password field instead of password with JWT ...

Comment: Please have a look at [this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-use-authentication-using-username-instead-of-email)

Comment: I try but I have the same problem, in my database I have a password column and a column bcrypt_password so I would like to use the column bcrypt_password instead of password

Answer (score 0):

Changing the login username is indeed easy. Changing the password field from the database is a little more tricky. In the file `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` you have to overwrite 2 methods:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
   $request->validate([
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        ' bcrypt_password' => 'required|string',
   ]);
 }
```

And

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->username(), 'bcrypt_password');
}
```

I haven't tested it but it should do the trick. The methods you have to overwrite are to be found in this Laravel class: `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` which is used in the `LoginController`.